# How do I make a application that I can run on other computers with a game made with python and pygame as well as an assets folder?

Tags: python, assets

Recently I made a basic 2d game in python using pygame and an assests folder within the same directory as my python file. I am wondering how I would condense this python file with the assests folder that contains images (.png) and audio files (.wav) into an application that I could share between computers and need no additional downloads to run and also if it would work betweem different operating systems (not essesntial but am wondering what my options would be for future similar projects) I have found many online resources about how to make a executable batch file from a python file but none of these examples contain an extra folder of assests like mine that are needed for the program to run correctly.

below is the full code for my game

```
import pygame
import os
pygame.font.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game!")

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

BORDER = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2 - 5, 0, 10, HEIGHT)

BULLET_DAMAGE_SOUND = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('Assets', 'Damage.wav'))
BULLET_SHOOT_SOUND = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('Assets', 'Shoot.wav'))
BULLET_WINNER_SOUND = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('Assets', 'Winner.wav'))
BULLET_DEATH_SOUND = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('Assets', 'Death.wav'))

HEALTH_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('impact', 40)
WINNER_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('permanent marker', 100)

FPS = 60
VEL = 5
BULLET_VEL = 7
MAX_BULLET = 5
SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 55, 40

YELLOW_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
RED_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 2

YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))
YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(
    YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 90)


RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_red.png'))
RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(
    RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 270)

SPACE = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
   os.path.join('Assets', 'space.png')), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))


def draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets, red_health, yellow_health):
    WIN.blit(SPACE, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, BORDER)

    red_health_text = HEALTH_FONT.render("Health: " + str(red_health), 1, WHITE)
    yellow_health_text = HEALTH_FONT.render("Health: " + str(yellow_health), 1, WHITE)
    WIN.blit(red_health_text, (WIDTH - red_health_text.get_width() - 10, 10))
    WIN.blit(yellow_health_text, (10,10))

    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (yellow.x, yellow.y))
    WIN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP, (red.x, red.y))

    for bullet in red_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, bullet)

    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, YELLOW, bullet)

    pygame.display.update()


def yellow_handle_movement(keys_pressed, yellow):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and yellow.x - VEL > -6:  # LEFT
        yellow.x -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and yellow.x + VEL + yellow.width < BORDER.x + 18:  # RIGHT
        yellow.x += VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and yellow.y - VEL > -2:  # UP
        yellow.y -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and yellow.y + VEL + yellow.height < HEIGHT - 10:  # DOWN
        yellow.y += VEL


def red_handle_movement(keys_pressed, red):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and red.x - VEL > BORDER.x + 7:  # LEFT
        red.x -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and red.x + VEL + red.width < WIDTH + 20.5:  # RIGHT
        red.x += VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP] and red.y - VEL > -5:  # UP
        red.y -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and red.y + VEL + red.height < HEIGHT - 10:  # DOWN
        red.y += VEL


def handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red):
    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        bullet.x += BULLET_VEL
        if red.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(RED_HIT))
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)
        elif bullet.x > WIDTH:
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)

    for bullet in red_bullets:
        bullet.x -= BULLET_VEL
        if yellow.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(YELLOW_HIT))
            red_bullets.remove(bullet)
        elif bullet.x < 0:
            red_bullets.remove(bullet)


def draw_winner(text):
    draw_text = WINNER_FONT.render(text, 1, WHITE)
    WIN.blit(draw_text, (WIDTH/2 - draw_text.get_width() /
                         2, HEIGHT/2 - draw_text.get_height()/2))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(2500)


def main():
    red = pygame.Rect(700, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    yellow = pygame.Rect(100, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)

    red_bullets = []
    yellow_bullets = []

    red_health = 10
    yellow_health = 10

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL and len(yellow_bullets) < MAX_BULLET:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(
                        yellow.x + yellow.width, yellow.y + yellow.height//2 - 2, 10, 5)
                    yellow_bullets.append(bullet)
                    BULLET_SHOOT_SOUND.play()

                if event.key == pygame.K_RCTRL and len(red_bullets) < MAX_BULLET:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(
                        red.x, red.y + red.height//2 - 2, 10, 5)
                    red_bullets.append(bullet)
                    BULLET_SHOOT_SOUND.play()

            if event.type == RED_HIT:
                red_health -= 1
                BULLET_DAMAGE_SOUND.play()

            if event.type == YELLOW_HIT:
                yellow_health -= 1
                BULLET_DAMAGE_SOUND.play()

        winner_text = ""
        if red_health <= 0:
            winner_text = 'Yellow Wins!'
            BULLET_DEATH_SOUND.play()

        if yellow_health <= 0:
            winner_text = 'Red Wins!'
            BULLET_DEATH_SOUND.play()

        if winner_text != "":
            draw_winner(winner_text)
            BULLET_WINNER_SOUND.play()
            break

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        yellow_handle_movement(keys_pressed, yellow)
        red_handle_movement(keys_pressed, red)

        handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red)

        draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets, red_health, yellow_health)

    main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: Also here is my project directory as it stands]

Thanks for all your help

So far i have had no luck :)

Comment: You can make a single file install package for your project and use python's `pip` on the computers to install. Include dependencies like pygame and python can pull them in too. There is a growing list of ways to do this (it can get confusing!) but you could start at [Python packaging user guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/#python-packaging-user-guide)

Comment: It becomes harder if you want this to run on computers which don't have Python installed. In that case you would have to use something like py2exe.